# Jenkins/Hudson JBoss plugin Shutdown did not work

Tags: ant, jboss, jenkins, hudson, shutdown

I have a JBoss instance running and was started through the Jenkins startup command in JBoss plugin. After my tests have run I would like to shutdown the JBoss server. However at this stage Jenkins informs me

```
SHUTDOWN: Checking if server is running (max 20 seconds)...
SHUTDOWN: JBoss AS is not working.
```

I verified after the run that JBoss indeed is still running. Any ideas what to do to fix this?

Comment: Could you please specify what command, plugin, script do you use to start and stop JBoss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, I had the wrong JNDI port Jenkins JBoss settings.